# echo HTML tag not working

Tags: php, html, css

For some reason when I am trying to print a welcoming message when the user logs on my site and make it styled in CSS. Whenever I try to do it, it prints the text not styled and after it it leaves `" ?>`

What is wrong?

Here is the CSS code for the class box

```
#box
{
border: 10px solid #a1a1a1;
padding: 120px 40px; 
width: 1163.5px;
border-radius: 25px;
}

<!---Submission Box--->
<div id="box">
<!---Welcoming Message--->
<?php
session_start();
echo "<div id="text">Hello, </div>"
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Missing semicolon and escape your quotes or use single quotes.

Comment: NONE OF THIS IS WORKING

Comment: No need for caps.. U need to place `session_start`before ALL output. Also be sure U are running a PHP enabled server

Comment: Its still leaving '; ?>  and the text is not styled

Answer (score 2):

You need to either escape the quotes you use if you wrap them with the same kind of quotes, or use different quotes. You should also have a semicolon at the end of the echo.

If you use the double quotes, PHP will parse the string and replace the variable with it's value. If you use single quotes you'll need to concatenate the string.

```
echo "<div id=\"text\" style=\"color:red;\" class=\"my-class\">Hello, $name</div>";
echo '<div id=\'text\' style=\'color:red;\' class=\'my-class\'>Hello, ' . $name . '</div>';
echo "<div id='text' style='color:red;' class='my-class'>Hello, $name</div>";
echo '<div id="text" style="color:red;" class="my-class">Hello, ' . $name . '</div>';
```

You should also move `session_start();` to the very top of your script before there is any output.

From your updated code, you still need to fix the quote issue. Place a semicolon at the end of the echo line. Move the `session_start();` to the header. You're not echoing any variable on the line so it's not necessary to use PHP to print out the HTML.

```
#box
{
border: 10px solid #a1a1a1;
padding: 120px 40px; 
width: 1163.5px;
border-radius: 25px;
}

<!---Submission Box--->
<div id="box">
<!---Welcoming Message--->
<?php
echo "<div id=\"text\">Hello, </div>";
?>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have any styles in your example. All you need to do is add those in and follow the same pattern with the quotes.

Comment: Maybe if I leave all of the source code it might help

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your quotes and move your `session_start()` to the top of the page:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
:
:
:    
<!---Submission Box--->
<div id="box">
<!---Welcoming Message--->
<?php
echo "<div id=\"text\">Hello, </div>";
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to **start the session before sending any output** (before the page headers would be written):

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!---Submission Box--->
<div id="box">
<!---Welcoming Message--->
<?php echo "<div id=\"text\">Hello, </div>"; ?>    
</div>
```

If you want to put `"` within `"` you have to escape it:

```
echo "<div id=\"text\">Hello, </div>";
```

As I understand you want to include a variable in the `echo`.
For example if you have the user's name in `$name` variable,
you can do this:

```
<?php echo "<div id=\"text\">Hello, $name</div>"; ?>
```

Comment: Yes but I need php variables in the hello div

Comment: Then you should have included that in your example. In that case, you can use the first version and embed the variables where you want.

Comment: Its still leaving me with the text and "; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Your double quotes are destroying your php!
You could use single quotes, and you are missing a semicolon:

```
<!---Submission Box--->
<div id="box">
<!---Welcoming Message--->
<?php
session_start();
echo "<div id='text'>Hello, </div>";
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Not styled and its still leaving "  ?>

Comment: it should work good...

Comment: It doesn't.. `Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by`

Comment: @DarkBee i just tested it, it works good on my website...

Comment: Nope. The session is not started because u have output before the session_start

Comment: Its not and the text is not styled

Comment: Look at this:http://viper-7.com/1Qpabc

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes or use back slash on the id quotes. Your choice. Also add in the ; at the end

**Method 1, single quotes**

```
echo '<div id="text">Hello, </div>';
```

**Method 2, back slash:**

```
echo "<div id=\"text\">Hello, </div>";
```

**My choice single quotes:**

```
<!---Submission Box--->
<div id="box">
<!---Welcoming Message--->
<?php
session_start();
echo '<div id="text">Hello, </div>';
?>
</div>
```